# Bro-cut and conn.log - how to access individuals columns?

Tags: logging, bro

How do you access the names of the columns in the Bro conn.log so that you can see what the fields are called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type:

```
 head -5 conn.log
```

you will see what the column names and types are.  You can then use bro-cut to extract the data:

```
 cat conn.log | bro-cut -d ts id.orig_h id.orig_p id.resp_h id.resp_p
```

Alternatively, you could simply do the following, which will print all columns with names:

```
 cat conn.log | bro-cut | head -3
```

This will let you see the column headers and a little bit of data from the log.